# Access Data from REST API in HIVE

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

Is there a way to create a hive table where the location for that hive table will be a http JSON REST API? I don't want to import the data every time in HDFS.

Comment: Are you asking if Hive (or Hadoop) exposes a JSON REST API for Hive databases? I think the answer to that is no. And unless you have some JSON SerDe over the data, it doesn't come out as JSON anyways. What is preventing you from writing a RESTful web-service that connects to Hive?

Comment: @cricket_007 I have lots of HIVE jobs which previously accessed data from some HIVE table. Now I need to point all those jobs to read data from some HTTP REST api which is replacing those hive tables. Could you please suggest a easiest way to do that?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you are asking. A REST API is not a replacement for Hive, in my opinion. Primarily because Hive is somewhat slow for the amount of data that it is intended to store. If you don't have that much data, then you could essentially be asking the same question about REST around a MySQL database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had encountered similar situation in a project couple of years ago. This is the sort of low-key way of ingesting data from Restful to HDFS and then you use Hive analytics to implement the business logic.I hope you are familiar with core Java, Map Reduce (if not you might look into Hortonworks Data Flow, HDF which is a product of Hortonworks).

Step 1: Your data ingestion workflow should not be tied to your Hive workflow that contains business logic. This should be executed independently in timely manner based on your requirement (volume & velocity of data flow) and monitored regularly. I am writing this code on a text editor. WARN: It's not compiled or tested!!

The code below is using a Mapper which would take in the url or tweak it to accept the list of urls from the FS. The payload or requested data is stored as text file in the specified job output directory (forget the structure of data this time).

**Mapper Class:**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;


public class HadoopHttpClientMap extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {
    private int file = 0;
    private String jobOutDir;
    private String taskId;

    @Override
    protected void setup(Context context) throws IOException,InterruptedException {
        super.setup(context);

        jobOutDir = context.getOutputValueClass().getName();
        taskId = context.getJobID().toString();

    }

    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{

        Path httpDest = new Path(jobOutDir, taskId + "_http_" + (file++));

        InputStream is = null;
        OutputStream os = null;
        URLConnection connection;
        try {
            connection = new URL(value.toString()).openConnection();
            //implement connection timeout logics
            //authenticate.. etc
            is = connection.getInputStream();

            os = FileSystem.getLocal(context.getConfiguration()).create(httpDest,true);

            IOUtils.copyBytes(is, os, context.getConfiguration(), true);

        } catch(Throwable t){
            t.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            IOUtils.closeStream(is);
            IOUtils.closeStream(os);
        }

        context.write(value, null);
        //context.write(new Text (httpDest.getName()), new Text (os.toString()));
    }

}
```

**Mapper Only Job:**

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;


public class HadoopHttpClientJob {
    private static final String data_input_directory  =  “YOUR_INPUT_DIR”;
    private static final String data_output_directory  =  “YOUR_OUTPUT_DIR”;

    public HadoopHttpClientJob() {
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        try {
            Configuration conf = new Configuration();

            Path test_data_in = new Path(data_input_directory, "urls.txt");
            Path test_data_out = new Path(data_output_directory);

            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            Job job = new Job(conf, "HadoopHttpClientMap" + System.currentTimeMillis());
            job.setJarByClass(HadoopHttpClientJob.class);

            FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);

            fs.delete(test_data_out, true);
            job.setMapperClass(HadoopHttpClientMap.class);
            job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
            job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
            job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
            job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);
            job.setNumReduceTasks(0);

            FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, test_data_in);
            FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, test_data_out);

            job.waitForCompletion(true);

        }catch (Throwable t){
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Step 2: Create external table in Hive based on the HDFS directory. Remember to use Hive SerDe for the JSON data (in your case) then you can copy the data from external table into managed master tables. This is the step where you implement your incremental logics, compression..

Step 3: Point your hive queries (which you might have already created) to the master table to implement your business needs.

Note: If you are supposedly referring to realtime analysis or streaming api, you might have to change your application's architecture. Since you have asked architectural question, I am using my best educated guess to support you. Please go through this once. If you feel you can implement this in your application then you can ask the specific question, I will try my best to address them.